# Rig following another rig scaling constraint problems

Tags: rigging, constraints, rigify

I've made a rig and then copied a part of that rig, the new copied rig will follow the part of the original rig that its copied from, its just scaled up, I've managed to do this with copy rotation constraints, however unless I also have copy scale the rig will scale uncontrollably aka it will stretch and squish even though the original isn't doing this.

But with copy scale I can no longer scale the new rig freely, keep in mind that I need to animate the scale of this new rig separately from the rig that its following.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?
to sum up I need to follow the animation of the old rig (achieved with copy rotation and copy scale), but I need to separately animate scale, and i can't since having copy scale off will result in squishing and stretching uncontrollably.

Further detail: 
with copy scale off individual bones will stretch and squish resulting in some bones to have 0 length and some to be super long unlike the original rig where bones don't change length, turning it on keeps the length equal but disables scaling of any kind, including armature scale (the entire thing) which is the thing I need to animate.
The rig is made with rigify, and the new rig is copying a part of the made rigify

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i figured it out

I turned off copy scale, and then for every bone that was having scaling problems I also turned off any IK constraints they had, since the rig is following another its no use having ik constraints on it anyway